# systemd-resolve and dnsmasq on a server

Tags: server, 20.04, dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved

i have the following issue on a server where i have `dnsmasq` installed:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
```

and that leads to some issues (e.g. clamav-freshclam is unable to refresh the virus definition files).

i can fix that manualy by

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolve
```

now everything seems fine.

`systemd-resolve` is enabled and should start on boot. but it does not.

i tried to set `DNSStubListener=no` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` as described over at [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-dnsmasq-and-systemd-resolved). but that did not help either.

there seems to be no conflict running both of them - it works when i start `systemd-resolve` manually.

how can i have a running `dnsmasq` and have `systemd-resolve` enabled at boot?

Comment: Read `man systemd-dnsmasq systemd`. Trying to use standalone `dnsmasq` in a `systemd` system will require you to learn way too much about `systemd`.

Comment: hmm. `man systemd-dnsmasq` does not exist. and in `man systemd` there is no mention of `dnsmasq`. Most resources on the internet suggest do disable `systemd-resolved.service`. i found nothing on `systemd-dnsmasq`. could you point me to a resource that describes what you mean?